# Explanation of mobx observables

Tags: javascript, mobx

I've recently started exploring libraries for state management in JavaScript, and I came across Mobx. I've tried searching through the web unable to find an explanation about what those observables really are. I understand what they do, but I'd like a deeper understanding of how they work. As a library the observables obviously makes things easier for us without having to reason about them much, but I still feel like I'd like an explanation.

Is Mobx "just" an implementation of the [observable pattern](http://anasfirdousi.com/understanding-observable-patterns-behind-observables-rxjs-rx.html), or does it deviate in some manner?

Comment: Read: https://medium.com/@mweststrate/becoming-fully-reactive-an-in-depth-explanation-of-mobservable-55995262a254

Comment: I did already, but it didn't answer the question. I just described how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to know how something works, it's often best just to look at [the code](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/master/src/core/observable.ts).

I'm no expert on the "observer pattern", but using @zvona's [link](http://anasfirdousi.com/understanding-observable-patterns-behind-observables-rxjs-rx.html) it seems to me that "yes, mobx is just an implementation of the observer pattern."

Rationale based on that post:

- `Defines a one-to-many dependency between objects so that when one object changes state, all its dependents are notified and updated automatically.`

  - note that `IObservable` has a property named `observers`
- `Observers explicitly ask Observables to add them to the observer list the Observable maintains.`

  - I'd say this is definitely something that happens in MobX via `addObserver`
  - Any new observer added to `observable.observers` array is of type [`IDerivation`](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/master/src/core/derivation.ts)
  - Note the comment in that file pointing you to [An in-depth explanation of MobX](https://medium.com/@mweststrate/becoming-fully-reactive-an-in-depth-explanation-of-mobservable-55995262a254)

---

*Does [MobX] deviate [from the observer pattern] in some manner?*

I already stated I'm not an expert in the textbook definition of the observer pattern. I couldn't find anything written by Michel Weststrate explicitly stating that MobX *is* an implementation of this pattern (not that I looked all that hard), but I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that (like most JavaScript libraries) there is some deviation from the textbook. But I don't know if it's worth nitpicking those.